# Liferay portal allows access to non-registered users

Tags: liferay

I'm using Liferay version 5.23.  It seems there's a problem with pages being accessed by non-registered users vi standard internet search. The documentation doesn't mention anything about restricting pages. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: If Community/Site pages are public then it will be accessible to Guest user/Non-registered user. You have to have Private type of pages to restrict it from Guest/Non-registered users.

Comment: Note that 5.2.3 is unmaintained and not updated for > 5 years now - it might have worse issues than this, so you really should update.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in the [Liferay Forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/48232299).

Jesse Rao answers there:

> Every Liferay site (community in Liferay 5.2) has both a public page
>   set and a private page set. If you add pages to the private page set
>   of a community, they won't be accessible to guest users (users who
>   have not logged in).

I consider it respectful to crossreference links to other places where you asked the same question in order to make people aware of existing answers and not generate duplicate work